# For Each Loop in SQL Server using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 4 cols.
HouseNo, Date, Time and Temp.

I have managed to obtain the different HouseNos in a separate table. Now i want to insert all the dates for all the house nos.

---

Sample Data from table. There are like a few million rows like this.

```
HouseNo Date Time Temp
102 1/1/2010 10:00 67
102 2/1/2010 10:00 73
102 3/1/2010 10:00 75
103 1/1/2010 10:00 69
103 2/1/2010 10:00 63
104 1/1/2010 10:00 71
104 2/1/2010 10:00 12
```

---

Expected Output is

table 1

```
102 1/1/2010 
102 2/1/2010 
102 3/1/2010
```

table 2

```
103 1/1/2010 
103 2/1/2010
```

table 3

```
104 1/1/2010 
104 2/1/2010
```

Then i want to be able to loop through each row in the tables derieved to perform some operation on the temperature field.

Comment: What _operation_ do you want to perform? Maybe it's possible to use set based operations instead of loops which are slow. Btw, why do you need three different tables for your three houses?

Comment: One bad idea = splitting data in different tables based on column value. Another bad idea = looping to perform operation on column. Both can easily be avoided.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic: Looping is a bad idea. I know that. But is there an alternative. If there is, I would love to have it.

Splitting Data temporarily only. Those Tables will then be deleted. Take them as Views and not Actual Tables.

Comment: @SarangArd: There is always an alternative http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them Here is a nice article that explains common miss-use of cursors and how to replace them with set based operation. If you can't manage to find a solution yourself, update your question or post a new one explaining the problem.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I wouldn't say that splitting the table up is a bad idea, actually it could be a great architectural decision. It would make great use of [partitioned views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx)... Of course, based on the basic question I don't know if that route is the intent :).

Answer (score 0):

If you have one ON/OFF pair per day and the OFF is always before the ON, this gets you the duration.

```
SELECT 
HouseNo,  
Date, 
DATEDIFF(s,
   MIN(CASE WHEN Relay='OFF' THEN Time ELSE NULL END),
   MIN(CASE WHEN Relay='ON' THEN Time ELSE NULL END)
) As OffDuration
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HouseNo,  Date
```

But any normal real life dataset will have multiple ON/OFF pairs. Can you give more detail?

Comment: Nope. It isn't. That data which i have put is just a sample. You have a record for every 20th second. And you have an extra field called Relay.

I want to find out where the Relay is Turned OFF in a given day. for how long.

Comment: I guess the relay can be turned on and off multiple times in a day? Do you want the outside ON/OFF to be captured or do want the sum of all the internal ON/OFF pairs to be calculated? Please state the exact requirement in the question and you'll get a good answer (which may or may not require cursors but probably won't require the data to be split into separate tables)

Comment: I have the Relay turned OFF and ON multiple times in a day.

I want the data to be captured only when the Relay is OFF. Be it for a minute or the whole day. All the Rows in a day that have Relay OFF. The rows might not be continuous.

Answer (score -1):

something like this ?

```
    CREATE TABLE new_table
    AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

you can also put some WHERE part and SELECT

Comment: That code is not valid in SQL Server. In SQL Server you would use `SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM OldTable` In Oracle that code would create a new table from data in the old table

Comment: yeah @ElectricLlama is right , but i'm just asking if that's that you want :P .